# RegEx to match and replace grammar words (v, n, adv, adj)

Tags: regex

I need to match workds "v", "n", "adv", "adj" and replace them as *v* etc.

I need them to be matched if they're written between braces `(...)` or between slashes `/.../`. 
They may have some trash symbols in the end like `, ;` etc.

So let's say I have:

```
abrasion n
air (v)
big /adj/
```

I need this result:

```
abrasion <i>n</i>
air (<i>v</i>)
big /<i>adj</i>/
```

I'm currently using this RegEx:

```
(?!(\B|\s|\/|\())(n|v|adj|adv)(?=(\s|$|\/|,|;|\)))
```

But it fails to work. I keep getting this kind of result:

```
abrasio<i>n</i>
```

Comment: Use word boundaries (\b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work for you:

```
\b([nv]|ad[jv])\b
```

Although it matches more cases than needed, it is unlikely to match anything you don't want to match.

The replacement would be `<i>\0<\i>` - `\0` is the *whole* match.

Comment: Tank you! So easy it appered to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundary `\b`.

Regex:

```
\b(ad[vj]|[vn])\b
```

Replacement string:

```
<i>$1</i>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/11)

Answer (score 0):

search : `(?<=\W)(v|n|adv|adj)(?=\W)`

replace with : `<i>\1</i>`

this seems to work :

http://regex101.com/r/tD9lC0/1